# Wireless AP/VPN

Tags: wifi, vpn, bridge

I'm attempting to follow the below links in the setup of a raspberry pi as a home AP/VPN.

https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/

https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-vpn-router/

I can't get it route through the VPN.

The setup in the first link appears to work correctly, as I can access the internet using an old simless phone connecting to the new AP, however the IP assigned to the device is not in the defined range. It appears because I'm bridging the eth0 and wlan0 that it defers to eth0 for the IP.

My instinct is telling me there is something wrong with bridge setup but I've no idea what is might be. Any feedback would be welcome.

Comment: Mostly likely you made a mistake in the configuration, but it will be hard for us to tell where unless you post your files.

Comment: Everything is verbatim as the per the links, using a fresh install of the latest raspbian (01-2018)